# How do I simplify this code in java without the resource of passing by reference?

Tags: java, c++

I've grown acostumed to use c++ pass by reference and now I'm starting to code more in Java. When solving a problem at leetcode I faced a problem: I tried to use this piece of code so I didn't have to rewrite this three lines often.

```
public void copyAndMoveNodes(ListNode tail, ListNode nodeToCopy) {
    tail.next = new ListNode(nodeToCopy.val);
    tail = tail.next;
    nodeToCopy = nodeToCopy.next;
}
```

I was expecting it to work similarly this in c++:

```
void copyAndMoveNodes(ListNode* &tail, ListNode* &nodeToCopy) {
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(nodeToCopy.val);
    tail->next = &newNode;
    tail = tail->next;
    nodeToCopy = nodeToCopy->next;
}
```

But I discovered I passed just the copy of the objects' references in java as writen in the first piece of code.

Is it possible to rewrite this in Java to work similarly? I use this sequence of three commands many times and I don't want to write them every time, it makes the code more confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do the equivalent of pass by reference for primitives in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-pass-by-reference-for-primitives-in-java)

Comment: [SO: How can I simulate pass by reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7884581/7478597)

Comment: [SO: Java pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9404625/7478597)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is an additional return value - for a mechanical translation.

```
param = f(param, x);
```

Very ugly when having two references:

- a void method with a parameter `ListNode[]`
- a void method with a parameter `Pair<ListNode, ListNode>`

Best would be give a **Stream** a try. On collection classes no problem, on node classes holding a next field, it can still be done as:

```
Stream.iterate(rootToCopy, node -> node.next != null, node -> node.next)
    .forEach(node -> { ... });
```

Even if it would be on a Pair of nodes or such.

So my conclusion: switch to the java collection classes and operate on entire lists
using `.stream()`. Knowing both sides C++ with the power of references, and java, I do not find it hard to have the more abstract style in java: performance still okay, readability fine, writability needing excercise, expressiveness and compactness excellent.

Porting the software in the first stage could be done best by **inlining** the method's code.

*One apology for java:* by language design `f(x)` will never change the *variable* `x` to
improve software quality / code checkers.

Comment: Are your comments concerning _performance, readability..._ about Java? Well, just type _'why is java'_ in the google search and see the suggestions ;)

Comment: @nada I understand I was overdoing a bit. I am not biased towards Java. The main point is that the mechanical translation (as nicely suggested by Scheff) often introduces more verbose code (than C++), and that is insatisfactory. I especially wanted to rewriting with java collections a bit more alluring. Reformulated slightly